# Toolbar bug with method setTitle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am using this two methods in my toolbar:

```
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

The reason for using `getSupportActionBar` is because `toolbar.setTitle("title");` is not working.

This is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the correct behavior.

You can find more info [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763).

Check the Chris Banes answer. Chris is working on the Android support libraries at Google.

> So we've decided that the current behavior is correct. Once you call `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`, the Action Bar is then responsible for handling the title, meaning that you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)` to set a custom title.

Then use:

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```